# How to delete the first value and trailing comma from the 7th column in a csv file

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv

I am trying to remove the first value from the 31st column in a csv file.
The columns are in quotes and separated by commas like so.

```
"first_name","last_name","home_address"
"Frank",Russel","123 Hampton road"
```

the 31st column is the image column and images are separated by commas

```
"http://ddd.com/124dfr3f.jpg,http://ddd.com/hjasgx37trg.jpg"
```

The first image and tailing comma has to be removed from the 31st column

**Added** - Here is an example.

```
"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","twenty-one","twenty-two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","thirty-one","thirty-two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","forty"
"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","twenty-one","twenty-two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","http://pictures.domain.com/e/josequervo/1183/eeeffcc7927sssssssssss5d26c0eb19e1dc53548x.jpg","http://pictures.domain.com/e/josequervo/0083/eeef8cc7927bf1245d26c0eb19e1dc53545x.jpg,http://pictures.domain.com/e/josequervo/0099/eeefscc7927bf1245d26c0eb19e1dc53546x.jpg,http://pictures.domain.com/e/josequervo/0012/eeefdcc7927bf1245d26c0eb19e1dc53547x.jpg,http://pictures.domain.com/e/josequervo/1183/eeeffcc7927bf1245d26c0eb19e1dc53548x.jpg,http://pictures.domain.com/e/josequervo/1234/eeefgcc7927bf1245d26c0eb19e1dc53549x.jpg,http://pictures.domain.com/e/josequervo/asee/eeefhcc7927bf1245d26c0eb19e1dc53540x.jpg,http://pictures.domain.com/e/josequervo/2341/eeefjcc7927bf1245d26c0eb19e1dc53544x.jpg","two",three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","forty"
```

This url and comma has to be removed

`http://pictures.domain.com/e/josequervo/0083/eeef8cc7927bf1245d26c0eb19e1dc53545x.jpg,`

I only posted the first 2 lines of the csv file but the file is 300 - 400 lines and this image has to be removed from line 2 to the last line. We can't alter the first line.

Comment: Does any other fields contain commas?

Comment: Is example wrong?  Should `"Frank",Russel","123 Hampton road"` read `"Frank","Russel","123 Hampton road"`, i.e. a `"` before `Russel` ?

Comment: Do you want to completely eliminate the 31st column, or replace it with an empty string to keep all the subsequent fields in the same ordinal positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `sed` we may approach this as shown:

```
sed -e '
     s/","/&\n/30
     s/\n[^,]*,//
' file.csv
```

To be understood as:

- Place a placeholder at the 30th occurrence of the `","` string in the current line.
- Then, traveling right from the placeholder all the way up to the first comma we delete everything along the way.

Other method is given as follows:

```
 perl -F'/","/' -lane 'my $i;
      print join q[","], map { $i++ == 30 ? substr($_, 1+index($_, ",")) : $_ } @F;
 ' input-file.csv
```

Method:

- perl will read the csv file on a line by line basis, and for each line it shall split it around the string  `","` and store the split elements in the array @F.
- Then for the 31st element, we remove everything up to the first comma.

Comment: This assumes (probably correctly) that the OP wants to completely delete the 31st field and not just its value.

Comment: @joe I just want to remove the first image url in the 31st column as it has around 6 images in this column. The first image is bad. Each image url is separated by a comma so the url and the trailing comma must go.

Comment: @needtoknow do the codes provided not generate the desired output?

Comment: @RakeshSharma They do not. Look at the bottom of  OP and see the example.

Comment: @needtoknow They work. You need to look carefully and follow the code as provided.

Comment: @RakeshSharma okay mate. I'll have a look.

Comment: ```sed -e 's/","/&\n/30; s/\n[^,]*,//' file.csv > final.csv && grep 'eeef8cc7927bf1245d26c0eb19e1dc53545x.jpg' final.csv```  Looking back at my notes, I misformed the one line command. This does work. I can't say sorry or thanks but I can say ... right on. Excellent!!!

Answer (score 0):

As per your question understood image  exsists in 31 st column seperated by comma and we need to remove first character from 31st column

```
awk -F "," '{$31=substr($31,2);print $0}' file.csv
```

Tested and its working fine Let us know for any confusion

Comment: cvs file is a profile dump of people. 31st column contains their images. The images in the 31st column are separated by commands. I need to remove the first image url and the comma after it on each line.

Comment: will update in some time

Comment: You probably have to set `OFS=","` to get commas as delimiters in the output.

Comment: Can you please post the sample input and expected output so we can help

Comment: @PraveenKumarBS Please see original post.

Comment: @Kusalananda see OP. I added an example of the expected outcome.